# Magento 2.2.4 : Way to get search result url (including the parameter)?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, search-result

Every time I type something something in the search bar, I get redirected to the following url:

```
https://XXXXXX.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=typed_text_on_search_bar
```

Is there a way to get the complete url through a php statement?

I tried this already:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955256/get-the-current-page-url-in-magento-2-0

but I only got this as result: `https://XXXXXX.com/catalogsearch/result/` without the parameter `?q=typed_text_on_search_bar`

Thanks for your inputs

Comment: can you share website URL?

Comment: Well, this is an staging environment which is protected from the outside; I guess I do not have permissions to share it;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet worked finally for me:

```
<?php
$query = "?product_list_limit=all";
$q = $this->getRequest()->getParam('q');
if($q)
$query .= "&q=$q";
?>

<a class="limiter" href="<?= $query ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('View all') ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code from Magento Term block
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Search/Block/Term.php#L123